# Is there a way to use wildcards for a windows directory path in a Gradle script?

Tags: windows, command-line, gradle, specflow

I have a Gradle script that needs to look in a file path for SpecFlow.exe.  The problem is, the path will include the current version of SpecFlow in the name.  Since I will be using similar scripts within many projects using SpecFlow, I don't want them to have to be coupled to a specific version in case we upgrade in the future.  This is what the task/command looks like currently:

```gradle
task testReports (type: Exec) {
    mkdir('testReports')
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '..\\packages\\SpecFlow.1.9.0\\tools\\specflow.exe','nunitexecutionreport', 'pathtocsproj/myproject.csproj', '/xmlTestResult:..\\nunitoutput_myproject.xml', '/out:testReports\\TestResult_myproject.html'
}
```

I tried the following:

```gradle
task testReports (type: Exec) {
    mkdir('testReports')
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '..\\packages\\SpecFlow.*\\tools\\specflow.exe', 'nunitexecutionreport', 'pathtocsproj/myproject.csproj', '/xmlTestResult:..\\nunitoutput_myproject.xml', '/out:testReports\\TestResult_myproject.html'
}
```

But that gave me an error: `"> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"`

Is there a way for me to include wildcards in this path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file tree - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html - with include filter matching `**/SpecFlow.exe` and then call its [http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#getSingleFile()](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#getSingleFile%28%29) and obtain path from it. Of course there is a question how you want to handle case when there are more versions of this package installed.